# Xtext with multilingual keywords

Tags: multilingual, xtext

Is it possible to create grammar with multilingual keywords? I'm implementing a dsl language with over 100 keywords, which have to be translated in multiple languages. Is there a way to achieve that with XText?
Below is an example of the dsl. The first line describes the keyword language. The second and the third line are examples of keywords in english and german

```
..language english 
.help 'index.html'
.select '1_2'

..language german 
.hilfe 'index.html'
.hole '1_2'
```

The dsl grammar is already defined and there are already files in different languages. Thus I have to create the editor and cannot change the grammar and the keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask for is certainly possible with Xtext. You can use a custom lexer yet have to make sure that you produce the very same token types as the original lexer does. You may want to check out the `org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.ex.ExternalAntlrLexerFragment`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm not really sure that I understand the purpose of this class. Does it generate the rules in the ´InternalParser´?

Comment: The pointer just serves as an entry point to see which constraints have to be taken into account if you want to come up with an own lexer, e.g. you have to respect the so called token vocabulary of the parser when your create custom tokens / split the string into keywords / identifiers by yourself. The approach is not something that's especially straight forward, though.